# Model Selection

Tags: model-selection

I have employed a variety of ML algorithms using 10-fold cross validation using the caret package in R on my data set. Can I employ ANOVA test on their f measures or Auc's to see if there is any significant difference between the models?

Comment: If so how to implement it in R?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the problem you are solving and how you are performing the 10 fold cross validation ?

Comment: I applied 10 fold cross validation using the caret package in R and now looking for a way to get the performance measure for each fold.